# How to sql server page_number Like row_number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pagination

Current context: Paging query results

i need to know if there is some way to get calculated value in my query like row_number, that calculates the next new value over a specific ammount of rows.

if i use row_number it will generate a kind on identity column in my result, whet i whant is to ger it over a specified ammout of rows. like this:

Number of rows per page: 3

```
RowNum, PageNum, Value
1, 1, rowa
2, 1, rowb
3, 1, rowc
4, 2, rowd
5, 2, rowe
6, 2, rowf
7, 3, rowg
```

Comment: `(ROW_NUMBER / ITEMS_PER_PAGE) AS PageNum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT 
      RowNum = ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY Value ASC),
      Value
   FROM 
      dbo.TableName
)
SELECT 
   RowNum,
   PageNum = ((RowNum - 1) / 3) + 1,
   Value
FROM 
   CTE
ORDER BY 
   RowNum ASC
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8690f/4/0)

Of course the `3` should be a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ranking function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx), with a `<partition_by_clause>`, which:

> Divides the result set produced by the FROM clause into partitions to
>   which the ROW_NUMBER function is applied. For the syntax of PARTITION
>   BY, see OVER Clause.

For instance `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)`:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PageNum
                       ORDER BY Id) AS  Rownumber
   FROM tablename
) 
...
```